# select the option with the highest data-sale attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

kind a new to jquery and cant get my head around on this one. any help would be much appreciate.

add checked attribute to the radio input with the highest data-attribute.

**But** :

**A**. if the radio input in the bottom of the list has an attribute disabled="disabled" select the second highest option.

e.g.

```
<ul class="sales">
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="20"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="50"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="55"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" checked="checked" data-sale="60"/></li><!--add checked attribute-->
<li><input type="radio" disabled="disabled" data-sale="90"/></li>
```

**B**. if the disabled attribute is not in the bottom of the list, still checked the highest radio.

e.g.

```
<ul class="sales">
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="20"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="50"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" disabled="disabled" data-sale="55"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" data-sale="60"/></li>
<li><input type="radio" checked="checked" data-sale="90"/></li><!--add checked attribute-->
```

naturally the html apply the checked in the very first radio in the list. in this case the data-sale = 20

i have to append that data-sale attribute to a container span.

thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: Google before you ask the question.... SO will help you only if you have tried and struck with that...

Comment: Please add what you've tried to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's what you need, but :
First,  use the same name for your radio's button, to link them.

```
    <ul class="sales">
    <li><input type="radio" name="rad" data-sale="20"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="rad" data-sale="50"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="rad"  data-sale="55"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="rad" data-sale="80"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="rad" disabled="disabled" data-sale="90"/></li>
    </ul>
Result :<span id="result"></span>
```

Here the Jquery code :

```
    var max_ds = 0;
    $.each($("input:radio"), function() {
    var data_sale = $(this).attr("data-sale");
    if (!$(this).prop('disabled')) {
        if (max_ds < data_sale) {
            max_ds = data_sale;
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
            $("#result").empty().append(data_sale);
        }
    }
    })
```

You can check on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hggek8ur/)

Comment: thanks for your response. well basically i do have a list of input:radio. the radio is pre-selected with the lowest data-sale, that is 20 and some radio have disabled attribute. it could be one or more radio has disable attribute, and the data-sale value is displayed in the span#result, what i need is that when the page load instead of checked the lowest data-sale it will checked the highest data-sale, in this case its 90. and on change it will update the span#result. your solution looks promising i am trying to implement this. what means my this condition? (!$(this).prop('disabled'))

Comment: (!$(this).prop('disabled')) = if the element doesn't have the property disabled